# CSS Width issue

Tags: html, css

So, I have a container dive with two divs contained in it.

```
#main_container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 980px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
border: none;
}
    .content_third {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 326px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: none;
    }

    .content_two {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 653px;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: none;
    }




<div id="main_container">
            <div class="content_third">
            hello world!

            </div>
            <div class="content_two">
            Hello World!
            </div>
        </div>
```

The divs stack vertically instead of lining up horizontally like I need. The widths add up (326px + 653px = 979px) so I can't figure out why they wont line up correctly. Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see the HTML, but the best guess is that you have something like this:

```
<div class="content_third">
    foo
</div>
<div class="content_two">
    bar
</div>
```

Because the both divs have `display: inline-block;` the whitespace between the divs becomes meaningful, that is, a space character is added between them. Change the HTML so that there's no whitespace (line breaks, spaces) at all between the divs:

```
<div class="content_third">
    foo
</div><div class="content_two">
    bar
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` is a block level element, each starts a new line by definition. You can either change that with `style="display: inline"` or use `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: Thats why I added the 'inline-block' to the elements. If I reduce either of the widths by 2px, the boxes line up.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content_third {
float:left; /*remove display:inline-block*/
width: 326px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
border: none;
}

.content_two {
float:left; /*remove display:inline-block*/
width: 653px;
vertical-align: top;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
border: none;
}


<div id="main_container">
            <div class="content_third">
            hello world!

            </div>
            <div class="content_two">
            Hello World!
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>    
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add this to the divs: `display: inline;` in CSS.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WFxA/

Comment: That results in the divs not taking up the required width.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `float: left;` to both the child DIVs elements.